# Menu bar not showing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I've added a a custom JPane and a custom JMenuBar to my JFrame. The JPane shows up just fine, but not the JMenuBar. I've defined the frame and the menu bar in different classes

Here's the frame class:
    public class pixelFrame { //This frame will hold the a pixelPane for art creation. This will also hold a menu bar, defined in another file.
    pixelPane editingArea;
    pixelMenuBar menuBar;
    public pixelFrame()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  //create a new thread at runtime

```
        @Override
        public void run() {  //when the program runs, do the following
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pixel Art Creator");  //create a new JFrame (similar to a regular window), and give it the following title
            editingArea = new pixelPane();
            menuBar = new pixelMenuBar();
            frame.add(editingArea);  //add a pixelPane named editingArea to the JFrame
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); //adds a menu to the JFrame
            frame.pack(); //make the window big enough to fit all components (in this case, editingArea)
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //set window to the center of the screen
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Stop the thread and terminate the program.
            frame.validate();
            frame.setVisible(true); //You can see the window.

            menuBar.setVisible(true);
        }

    });
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    pixelPane.gridEnabled = true; //changing another variable from pixelPane just for testing.
    new pixelFrame(); //create an instance of pixelFrame.
}
```

}

And here's the menu bar:

```
public class pixelMenuBar extends JMenuBar {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu file, tool;
JMenuItem save, load, changeColor;
JCheckBoxMenuItem gLines;
public pixelMenuBar() {
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //creates a "File" menu in the menu bar
    file= new JMenu("File");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    menuBar.add(file); //add the menu to the menu bar

    //creates a "Tools" menu in the menu bar
    tool = new JMenu("Tools");
    tool.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menuBar.add(tool);


    //Menu items that go under the File menu
    save = new JMenuItem("Save File"); //save and export the image as an .svg file
    save.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_S)); //a Ctrl+S hotkey. Handy dandy!
    file.add(save);//adds the Save button to the File menu

    load = new JMenuItem("Load File"); //load the file into BufferedImage, make it into a JLabel and add it to the panel.
    load.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_L));//a Ctrl+L hotkey. Also handy dandy!
    file.add(load);//adds the Load button to the File menu


    //Menu items that will go under the Tools menu
    gLines = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Gridlines"); //creates a new checkbox for enabling grid lines. will toggle pixelPane.gridEnabled
    gLines.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK,KeyEvent.VK_G));
    tool.add(gLines);//adds the gridlines tool to the Tools menu
    tool.addSeparator(); //adds a separating line in the Tools menu. Organization.

    changeColor = new JMenuItem("Change Color");//creates a new menu item that will let the user the color of the pixel. Uses a color picker
    tool.add(changeColor);//adds Change Color to the Tools menu
}
```

}

Am I not adding something to the UI correctly? I double checked that I'm using addJMenuBar() and not addMenuBar().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a class in the Java API that doesn't? Follow Java conventions. Learn by example.

```
public class pixelMenuBar extends JMenuBar 
{
...
public pixelMenuBar() 
{
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
```

Your class "is a " JMenuBar, but the first thing you do in the class is create a JMenuBar.

Don't create the JMenuBar!

Just add the menu items to the JMenuBar class itself:

```
//menuBar.add(file); //add the menu to the menu bar
add(file); //add the menu to the menu bar
```

In reality there is no need to even have a PixelMenuBar class, since you are not adding any new functionality to the JMenuBar. Just add a method to your main class like `createMenuBar(...)` that creates the JMenuBar and adds the JMenu/JMenuItem objects.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, I should delete `JMenuBar menuBar;` and `menuBar.add(file)` because PixelMenuBar "is a" JMenuBar already? 
Also my reasoning behind having PixelMenuBar is for organization's sake so I'm not scrolling and reading through several lines in one file just for the menu's code. Having it in a separate file is easier for me to organize.